# Determine when a socket is destroyed NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, socket.io

When the user closes the window, how can I tell if a socket is destroyed?

In my code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {...})
```

is there a `io.on('disconnect', function(socket)` or something? I want `io.emit` that a particular socket has closed or finished.

Comment: Is this regarding [socket.io](https://socket.io)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sorry yes, I've added the tag.

Comment: What's the problem with using io.on('disconnect')?

Comment: @Tomzan Does it exist? I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @Chud37 answered.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO have a disconnect event: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/ look for "Event: 'disconnect'"

Just make sure it's inside you 'connect' block

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the particular `socket` object's [`disconnect`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-disconnect) event:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    // socket has been disconnected
  })
})
```